# Converting Java method to c or objective c

Tags: java, objective-c, char, int

My problem is i have java method i need to convert this objective i am trying this but its returning zero

```
-(char *)intToByteArray:(char *)data{
int iii13=((int)((data[0]>>24),(data[1] >>16) ,(data[2] >>8),(data[3]>>0)));
char* where = (char*)malloc(10);
where[0] = *((char*)(&iii13) + 0);
where[1] = *((char*)(&iii13) + 1);
where[2] = *((char*)(&iii13) + 2);
where[3] = *((char*)(&iii13) + 3);
// 0
// char *www11 = (char *)www13; 
return where;  
}
<=====================Java Code================> is below

public static final byte[] intToByteArray(int value) {
    return new byte[] {
            (byte)(value >>> 24),
            (byte)(value >>> 16),
            (byte)(value >>> 8),
            (byte)value};
}
```

I want **return char** itself so can anyone suggest me the proper way

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean?

```
 // assuming you have a little endian processor.
 long* where = (long*) malloc(4);
 *where = value;
 return (char *) where;
```

Comment: then also it is returning zero itself

Comment: You mean 4 zeros right? because if you give it a number less than 16 million the first byte is going to be 0.